# GZIPInputStream: Can't read online .gz file correctly line by line

Tags: java, http, gzip

I want to read GZIP files(including thousands of number id) which I'm accessing through HTTP line by line.sometimes it can read correctly,but not correctly more;
This is my current approach:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
List<Long> list = Lists.newArrayList();
URL url = new URL("xx.gz");
try{
   br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(url.openStream())));
   String line = null;
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
       if (NumberUtils.isDigits(line)) {
           try {
               list.add(Long.valueOf(line));
           }catch (Exception e){
               logger.error("parse line:{} error:",line,e);
               continue;
           }
           if (list.size() == 20) {
             //batch handle
             list = Lists.newArrayList();
           }
       }
   }
}catch (Exception e){
   logger.error("handle file error:",e);
}finally {
   if(br != null){
      br.close();
   }
}
```

I find lots of "parse line" error log cause line is larger than Long.MaxValue（eg: 10352194518417219194627517808180732445615956450138943）; when i download the GZIP file and find there isn't such line larger than Long.MaxValue;

JAVA version  ： 1.8

OS Version ： CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

first few hundreds of line can read correctly,then log shows read unordered nums don't exist in the file.

After some tests and aceess some information on the Internet,

I guess server push file to the memory quickly then client read and handle slowly which may lead to memory leak.  then server initiatively close while tcp connection still alive. At this moment,client may get error data untill all data in the memory is read.

finally it's my first question in stackoverflow, sorry for lack of standardization of representation.

Comment: what is the real correct content of the zipped file? maybe the new line characters are not recognized (you get in one line numbers from several lines)?

Comment: when I try to download the gzip file and read file locally,  it works correctly.  but i still cannot figure out why I can't read correctly online with stream process.

Comment: each line is a num id with line characters (\n)   and the file use UTF-8 encode

Comment: firstly i use LineIterator and UTF-8 encode, then have the same result ;  code is :           LineIterator lineIterator = IOUtils.lineIterator(new GZIPInputStream(url.openStream()), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

Comment: I find how to reproduce this problem. read GZIP files through HTTP long time(batch handle cost a little time).firstly it works correctly.After several minutes,read line by line will occur errors.   Suggest  download file firstly if you need read long time.   But how it occurs i still can't figure out.

Comment: I mean, did you compare the numbers what you get in your code and the correct ones? When you download it, how do you read it locally? In notepad, or by your program as well? Did you analyze, where the difference is?
What is the url? Do you open a http connection? Please provide more info.

Comment: I download file and search num(the error log record) in the file,then find nothing. Read file locally by my program work correctly. The url is a gzip file contains millions userId by lines which is not suitable to let out. each line is not larger than Long.MaxValue.

Answer (score 1):

> I find lots of "parse line" error log cause line is larger than `Long.MaxValue`（eg: `10352194518417219194627517808180732445615956450138943`.  When I download the GZIP file and find there isn't such line larger than `Long.MaxValue`;

The error is coming from these lines:

```
   if (NumberUtils.isDigits(line)) {
       try {
           list.add(Long.valueOf(line));
       }catch (Exception e){
           logger.error("parse line:{} error:",line,e);
           continue;
       }
       ...
   }
```

First of all, your diagnosis is not correct.  The problem is not caused lines that are larger (longer) than `Long.MaxValue`.  The problem is that the lines *represent* numbers that are larger than `Long.MaxValue`.  That causes `Long.valueOf` to fail.

So, this is not a problem with the GZipStream or HTTP or downloading or the encoding of the file or some of the other things that commentators have speculated about.  And it is not (really) a problem with the lines being too long.  (That line is only about 55 characters long.)

The problem could that you have chosen the wrong way to represent the (apparently valid) numbers that you are reading from the file.

So what representation *should* you use?

It depends what these numbers mean:

- If they are really integers, use `BigInteger`.
- If they are actually multiple integers "smooshed together" in some way, you could try parsing them.  This assumes that you understand the format and/or the "smooshing" process.
- If they are actually identifiers of some kind, use `String`.

---

Alternatively, it could be that there is a bug in the software that is generating the file you are reading.  For example, it might be (incorrectly) joining two or more numbers together into a single line.

But you would be in a better position to know that than us.  We have no idea what your file is supposed to mean ... and whether *really large* numbers are actually valid data.

---

Alternatively, it could be that you have misunderstood the description, specification, examples, conversation, or whatever ... where the file format was explained.